# add jquery to parameters in custom widget type in magento2

Tags: magento2, widget

I have created a custom widget type using below code

```
<widget id="test" class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Widget\Test">
    <label translate="true">Namespace - Test</label>
    <description>Test Block</description>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="Test_title" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" sort_order="1" >
            <label translate="true">Test Title</label>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="Test_url" required="true" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" sort_order="1" >
            <label translate="true">Test URL</label>
            <depends>
                <parameter name="Test_type" value="0"/>
            </depends>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="Test_new" required="true" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" sort_order="1" >
            <label translate="true">Paste anything</label>
            <depends>
                <parameter name="Test_type" value="1"/>
            </depends>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="Test_description" required="true" xsi:type="text"  visible="true" sort_order="1" >
            <label translate="true">Test Description</label>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</widget>
```

Now i want to add some jquery code to parameter `Test_new` to validate user data or something similar. How i can do that.

Or how i can add a button attach to that parameter `Test_new` to open a text field or text area and add some jquery code to that functionality?

Any suggestion or reference would be helpful!!